# Html window rezise

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making an html website as a startpage for my phone.
But it doesn't fit(https://i.gyazo.com/4e1f9d56390168593f3f51c9be8cb42e.png). And it does not want to resize properly.
Html:

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="div">
<div align="top">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Youtube"><img src=" images/youtube.png"/></a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Google"><img src=" images/google.png"/></a>
</div>
<div align="top">
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Tumblr"><img src=" images/tumblr.png"/></a>
<a href="#" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Aperture"><img src=" images/aperture.png"/></a>
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.com" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Wikipedia"><img src=" images/wikipedia.png"/></a>
<a href="about" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Made By ThuverX Designs"><img src=" images/thuverx.png"/></a>
</div>
<a href="http://mail.google.com" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Gmail"><img src=" images/gmail.png"/></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" style="background-color:fff;" class="blur" title="Twitter"><img src=" images/twitter.png"/></a>
<div align="left">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=jacksepticeye" width="516" height="290"class="border"></iframe>         
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Css

```
.blur {
  border: 0;
  background-size: 80px 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
.blur:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}

.border{
    border: 0;
}

.div{

}
```

Picture: http://i.gyazo.com/fdb2d38783396a7350a6dbaf57aaa023.png

Does anybody know a fix?
(If jQuery, tell me how, I know nothing about it.)

Comment: what do you mean by it does not fit ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/4e1f9d56390168593f3f51c9be8cb42e.png

Answer (score 1):

```
html,body
{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
}
```

> Note: I would suggest you to have a look on media queries.
>   http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css3-media-queries.html#fbid=yf-U4qYzkTA

Comment: Tried the code but didn't work but i'l try the link

Comment: That is because of CSS for rest of your html elements(div,span,img - tags). Try also giving width:100% to class div

Comment: I tried this: html,iframe,body,div,img{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
} It resulted in this:http://i.gyazo.com/775e6a6ae5476750081b005727a63046.png

Comment: See i told you to give only for the class name with div, which contains your whole code.

Comment: Only using div, just resets it. To the not fitting version

Comment: Create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/). It would be much easier to debug